# Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I am making the switch to `biblatex` and I was wondering whether there are any disadvantages to using the `natbib=true` compatibility option.

I am sure we can all sympathise that journals will probably never make the switch to `biblatex`, so I think it would be wise to write my documents using the traditional `natbib` syntax which will allow me to transfer text directly from, say, my thesis to a paper I am writing up for Journal X.

But I would also like to know whether there are any disadvantages to using the compatibility option for the write up of my thesis. Will I end up sacrificing some super `biblatex` tricks that I am unaware of, or is `natbib=true` simply a series of macros that replace `natbib` commands with `biblatex` commands?

In case anyone needs to demonstrate something, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{citation,
  title     = {How To Live Underwater},
  author    = {Squarepants, SpongeBob},
  journal   = {Journal of Marine Biology},
  pages     = {1--8},
  year      = 2006,
  month     = jan,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent``How is babby formed?'' \parencite{citation} \\
``How is babby formed?'' \citep{citation}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: as far as I know, the natbib option with biblatex only provides the commands from natbib, the actual processing is done by biblatex and is not influenced by the option.

Comment: Yes, the processing is definitely done by the `backend` the user provides. But I was just wondering whether there are any disadvantages (e.g., reduced functionality) to just using the `natbib` commands.

Comment: Does section **3.7.9 natbib Compatibility Commands** of the `biblatex` manual answer your question?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It does, but I wasn't entirely sure what was meant by this: "However, the compatibility style will adapt `\nameyeardelim` to match the default style of the natbib package.". Hence the question. It seems like there should be no issues.

Comment: `\nameyeardelim` is just whatever separates the author and the year in a citation, e.g. in *(Author, 2014)*, `\nameyeardelim` is a comma followed by a space. Hence, it will change it to whatever is the `natbib` default.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Great. Sounds sensible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `natbib` option for `biblatex` causes the `blx-natbib.def` file to be loaded and not much else. There may be some styles that do different things depending on if the `natbib` option has been used, but the `authoryear` style does not seem to care. The `blx-natbib.def` file defines a handful of macros to recreate `natbib` citation commands, but it does not disable any `biblatex` functionality.

In regards to the comment about `\nameyeardelim`, one of the first things `blx-natbib.def` does is

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

You can undo this after loading `biblatex` with

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

In newer versions of biblatex (>= 3.4) you could use

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

although you will get a different typeset result if you then switch to `bibtex` and `natbib`.

Comment: It may be worthy of note that the handling of the starred form of the citation commands differ between the `biblatex`-name and the `natbib`-name. The `natbib` names also try to reproduce the `natbib` behaviour for the star. Compare `\citep{aksin} \citep*{aksin} \parencite{aksin} \parencite*{aksin}` when you cite `aksin` from `biblatex-examples.bib`. That is just to say that contrary to what one might be inclined to think `\citep` is not exactly just a short name for `\parencite`.