# Forcing `et al.` in selected places

Tags: tables, biblatex, natbib

I am using `XeLaTeX` together with `biblatex`. I am typesetting a table where a citation goes into one of the column headers, namely I put `\citet{ref1}` into the table.

`ref1` has two authors and normally the citation `AuthorA and AuthorB (2013)` looks fine in the text; however, in the table it is too wide so I was hoping to force `biblatex` to shorten it to `AuthorA et al. (2013)`.

Is there a way to do that? Note that I do not want to do it document-wide, only within the particular table.

*NOTE:* Using `\citeauthor` produces both names.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, natbib=true, backend=biber, sorting=nyt, autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@ARTICLE{ref1,
  AUTHOR = {AuthorA, A. and AuthorB, B.},
  JOURNALTITLE = {{Journal of Testing}},
  PAGES = {1--2},
  TITLE = {{Test Reference}},
  VOLUME = 1,
  NUMBER = 1,
  YEAR = 2013
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{ref1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The abbreviation _et al._ means _et alii,_ which is Latin for _and others_ (plural). Using it for a single co-author doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: There aren't many ways to shorten the author list so this has to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following does the trick:

```
\AtNextCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}\citet{ref1}
```

Comment: +1. This indeed is the right trick. But I wonder why there is not a `maxcitenames` counter...

Comment: Perhaps this could be a feature request.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need to have `natbib=true` then the command `\citeauthor*` does exactly that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber, sorting=nyt, autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@ARTICLE{ref1,
  AUTHOR = {AuthorA, A. and AuthorB, B.},
  JOURNALTITLE = {{Journal of Testing}},
  PAGES = {1--2},
  TITLE = {{Test Reference}},
  VOLUME = 1,
  NUMBER = 1,
  YEAR = 2013
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor*{ref1} 

\citeauthor{ref1}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

For what it's worth, I've discovered that with `natbib=true` and `maxcitenames=1`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, natbib=true, maxcitenames=1, backend=biber, sorting=nyt, autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@ARTICLE{ref1,
  AUTHOR = {AuthorA, A. and AuthorB, B.},
  JOURNALTITLE = {{Journal of Testing}},
  PAGES = {1--2},
  TITLE = {{Test Reference}},
  VOLUME = 1,
  NUMBER = 1,
  YEAR = 2013
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor*{ref1}

\citeauthor{ref1}

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: Could the part about `natbib` compatibility impact on the recent 'is there any downside to this option' question?

Comment: I upvoted the answer because it would have helped, but unfortunately at this stage into the writing process I can no longer give up `natbib` commands.

Comment: @Up-and-comingLaTeXMastah Thank you. I'll leave the answer, since it could be helpful to someone else. :-)

Comment: @Joseph Forgive my poor understanding of English, but I really don't know what you mean

Comment: @karlkoeller In your answer here you say 'If you don't need to have `natbib=true`', so I wondered if there is a link to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149313/is-there-a-disadvantage-to-using-natbib-true-with-biblatex/149320?

Comment: @Joseph I'm not sure about full compatibility. `\citeauthor` (starred and unstarred version) seems to behave the same way but `\citet` seems not.