# Force et al. for specific citations with natbib's longnamesfirst (must use natbib)

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am entering citation information in a table and need an article to use "et al." within the table.  However, the journal's style requires longnamesfirst.  Is there any way to force et al. for specific cases?  I tried \citeauthor*{} as suggested some places (but that's not a natbib command).  I also tried `\AtNextCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149799/70816)

I cannot change the style, or remove the longnamesfirst. I also cannot just manually type in as that wrecks the hyperlinks and automated bibliography.

MWE (although not the correct style file, but it shows the problem)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\title{random test document}

\begin{document}
Document with some words and a citation to an article with a lot of authors: \citeauthor{thearticle}.
 
\maketitle

\bibliography{name}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `natbib` citation management package offers the `\shortcites` macro to list the entry, or entries, which should get a truncated citation call-out even if the `longnamesfirst` option is in force.

[image]

It's best to place the `\shortcites` directive in the preamble (*after* loading `natbib`, of course).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{name.bib}
@misc{abcdef, author = "Aaa and Bbb and Ccc and Ddd and Eee and Fff",
              title = "Thoughts", year = 3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib style
\shortcites{abcdef} % <--- new
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{abcdef}
\bibliography{name}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Esme_ -- Please advise whether this answer was useful to you. If it was, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.