# IEEE style in biblatex with maxname

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
sorting=none,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=true,
%maxnames=1,
style=ieee,]{biblatex}
```

What I want: use IEEE format, but put et. al. after max 1 or 2 names according to my need. Don't want to edit the actual `.bib` file. Don't want to use `\nocite{*}`. Giving conflict error whenever I want to use `maxnames=1` or 2 with ieee style. However omitting ieee style if I use `maxnames=1`, it produces accurate result but changes the style.

1. How to overcome this?
2. What is `natbib=true` used for?
3. What is the best for bibliography in Engineering domain?

Comment: As you know on this site we prefer to ask one question per question to keep things simple and helpful for others. Since your questions were easy to answer I tackled all of them, but for future reference you might want to think about splitting multiple questions. (Q3 is (borderline) off-topic/too broad/primarily opinion-based anyway.)

Comment: @moewe thanks for the suggestion, my primary ask is Q1. While searching on the topic, I came to know the`natbib`, part Q2. I asked Q3, if anyone has personal opinion.

Comment: BTW: If you plan to ask more complex questions in the future, you may want to [read up on MWEs and how to construct them](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Especially with non-tivial `biblatex` questions an MWE can really be useful to others because they can test their solutions. That way you can make sure that all the necessary information to answer the question is on the table.

Comment: On 'what style to use': the idea of `biblatex-ieee` is to follow the rules of the IEEE as far as possible. I'd normally say _don't adjust this_: the entire point of following a publisher style is that it's a norm in an area!

Comment: @JosephWright yes, but sometimes due to page limitation it requires.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ad 1) `biblatex-ieee` sets `maxcitenames = 3, minnames = 3,` in the `.cbx` and `maxnames = 999, minnames = 3,` in the `.bbx`. This results in `maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=999, mincitenames=3, minbibnames=3`.

The `min<names>` counter must always be less or equal to the `max<names>` counter, so `maxnames=1,` conflicts with the min settings of `3`. So you will have to change both `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames`.

You would use

```
maxcitenames=2,
mincitenames=1,
```

to change the citations only.

In the discussion below it emerged that you want to change (primarily) the behaviour in the bibliography, so

```
maxnames=2,
minnames=1,
```

should give you what you want. As that changes both `maxcitenames` (for citations) and `maxbibnames` (for the bibliography) and `mincitenames` (for citations) and `minbibnames` (for the bibliography) respectively.

Ad 2) `natbib=true` enables the `natbib` compatibility mode. You can then use `\citep` as alias for `\parencite`, `\citet` for `\textcite`. Additionally some of `natbib`'s cite alias feature is implemented. Note that the starred versions of the cite commands differ between standard `biblatex` and `natbib` mode. (See also §3.8.9 *`natbib` Compatibility Commands* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and [Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with `biblatex`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864).)
If you don't need `\citet` as alias for `\textcite`, you probably don't need `natbib=true`.

Ad 3) What is the "best" style is a purely subjective choice. If you happen to write for/under the supervision of anybody (that includes thesis instructors, publishers, journals, ...), the best style is what they tell you to use. If you don't have any instructions on style use what you like best or what seems to be the norm in your field.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
sorting=none,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=true,
maxcitenames=2,
mincitenames=1,
style=ieee,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson} \textcite{sigfridsson}

\textcite{aksin,baez/article,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

then gives

> [1] Sigfridsson and Ryde [1]
>
> Aksın *et al.* [2], Baez and Lauda [3], and Worman [4]

Comment: I don't have any `.bbx` or `.cbx` files (or have I?). Where to put them? Want to use this only for particular documents. Hence should not conflict with other writeups. 1. Should I put these two files in the current working directory?

Comment: @Mr.EU You have them, they are the files that are loaded automatically if you say `style=ieee`. You don't need to change those files at all (and you should not), that part is just for explanation where the problem comes from. The solution is to use `maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1,` instead of `maxnames=1,` in your document when you pass the options to `biblatex`.

Comment: I understand the solution your solution. Thanks for the effort. However when I added `maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1,` to my `.tex` file as shown in MWE, it is not effecting on the generated pdf. Nevertheless, **`maxnames=2, minnames=1,` working**. What is the difference between `maxnames` and `maxcitenames`?

Comment: @Mr.EU It does affect the PDF as you can see in my MWE if you delete the line. It does not, however, affect the bibliography, the changes only apply to citations (hence `maxcitenames`, `mincitenames`). If you want to affect the bibliography as well you need `maxnames=2, minnames=1,` which sets both `min`/`maxcitenames` for citations and `min`/`maxbibnames` for the bibliography.

Comment: @Mr.EU Needless to say that while I would not mind cutting the list of authors short with "et al." in citations; shortening the author list in the bibliography seems a bit unnecessary to me, in general I would include all authors in the bibliography (OK there are some papers with >100 authors).

Comment: I don't know why, but unfortunately, in my system `min/maxcitenames` does not change in my **reference** section as well as my `.bib` file. `min/maxnames` makes desired changes in **reference** section as well as it does not edit/change my `.bib` file. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.EU That is what I'm saying `min`/`maxcitenames` obviously only applies to the *citations*, hence the name. You can see that in the MWE above, where the citations are different without the lines I suggested. If you use `min`/`maxnames`, not only the `min`/`maxcitenames` counter is set, but also `min`/`maxbibnames`, which (as the name part *bib* suggests) changes the output in the bibliography/references section. Neither of the options actually manipulates your `.bib` file.