# Natbib not compatible with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I do not like the way the commands `\cite` or `\parencite` produce page numbers. If I give a command `\cite[43]{XXX2015}`, it produces:

> XXX2015, p.43.

What I would like is:

> XXX2015:43.

I understand that the command `\citet` is supposed to give me this, and I also understand from searching around that I should load the `natbib` package to get that. However, there is some compatibility issue related to what I already have in my preamble. I guess it must be the `biblatex` package or `backend` package (if that is indeed a package). If I just load the `natbib` package I get the error message:

```
command \bighang already defined.
```

Can I continue to use the `backend` package with this setting and just add something? Here is a MWWW:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, sortcites=false, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=4, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

Blablabla. \cite[43]{Wolfe2015} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `biblatex` has a `natbib` option to emulate these natbib commands. See p. 6 of the documentation of biblatex.

Comment: I have read page 6, none the wiser. In any case, I am using Biber with Biblatex as an extension, if I am not mistaken. So it don't manage to emulate natbib with this particular setting..

Comment: In the one of the sections linked to,it's explained, if I remember well , that `\citet` and `citep` commands are defined to emulate the corresponding commands of `natbib`. I can't say more, not using natbib personally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`natbib` and `biblatex` are indeed incompatible. `biblatex` is incompatible with most bibliography management packages, since it implements citations and bibliography in a way that is fundamentally different from the traditional BibTeX way of doing things. Normally that is not too bad, since `biblatex` can do many things out of the box so that the extra packages are not needed.

Fortunately `natbib` is irrelevant to your issue. `biblatex` can do what you want without additional packages (and without the `natbib` compatibility mode, that I would avoid if it is not necessary, see also [Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864)).

You only need to redefine the `postnote` formats to stop printing the page prefix. Then we change the punctuation between citation and postnote to a colon.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, sortcites=false, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=4, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}

\begin{document}
\autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Incidentally, `\citet` would normally give citations of the form

> Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)

the `biblatex` equivalent to `\citet` is `\textcite` (just like the equivalent to `\citep` is `\parencite`). The `natbib` compatibility mode allows you to write `\citet` to get `\textcite` with `biblatex`, but it also changes the behaviour of the starred versions and changes some punctuation ([Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864)).

Comment: Typically you wouldn't have a space after the colon.

Comment: @AlanMunn Not even a thin/small space? I think long labels like the one in my example could benefit from a bit more space. But the question does not want a space and come to think of it when I see a colon used in that position I normally don't see a space either, so I have removed it.

Comment: Yeah, English is not French. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn But wouldn't the French also put a space before the colon?

Comment: Oh probably. Vive la ponctuation libre!

Comment: Thanks @moewe, but adding those lines to the preamble did not work, apparently, since I now get an error message related to the first use of \cite in the document: " ! Undefined control sequence. \blx@theformat #->\mkrnormrange...

Comment: @EspenJK In that case you are using an [older version of `biblatex`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/cf10ace65d4fa8b3db00c2dab093a218dce7d072/doc/latex/biblatex/CHANGES.md#release-notes-for-version-311). Add `\providecommand*{\mknormrange}[1]{#1}` to your preamble or update to `biblatex` 3.11.

Comment: @moewe, I added your command and now it works. I guess it might be preferable in the long run to update biblatex instead, but I have two until the deadline of my thesis, so I will do that afterways. Thanks for the help! Btw, not sure whether I should  accept your answer above or not. Perhaps you want to add your last command to the answer as well first...?

Comment: @EspenJK It is a wise decision not to rush into updating packages shortly before a deadline. I would rather not add the work-around for older `biblatex` to the answer, though, because usually I like to encourage people to use the current code.

Comment: @moewe, I now found out that, after adding your line, \parencite and \citep give the same result, which is to give "author, year" (the same applies to \cite now). I should like to remove the comma between them and only have "author year"... Do you know an easy solution?

Comment: @EspenJK What line specifically? As you can see from the screenshot the MWE does not have a comma there. The standard separator between author and year is a space, if you use the `natbib` compatibility mode `natbib=true` that changes to a comma and space (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864). If you don't need `\citep` and are OK with `\parencite` just remove the `natbib=true`. If you must have `natbib=true` you will want `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}` or in older versions `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}`.

Comment: @moewe, I removed the natbib=true and that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! \textcite helped me get Author(Year) form in my overleaf biblatex file. But \parencite gives (Author Year) format, how do I get (Author, Year) form ?

Comment: `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541559/35864.