# \citep vs. \parencite

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I work for long time in a document where I use biblatex with following parameters

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,maxcitenames=\preamblemaxcitenames,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,%
maxbibnames=10,sorting=nyt,natbib=true,sortcites=no]{biblatex}
```

Now, it comes to pass that I have two commands, `\citep` and `\parencite`—I forgot why I have this mix. The point is that I cannot see the difference at first sight.

```
\citep{knuth2001things} \parencite{knuth2001things}
```

Produces exactly the same:

[image]

Used like that, is there any fundamental difference between both, or advantage in using one over the other?
(I do not know, if it would be wise to change all `\citep` to `\parencite` or `\parencite` to `\citep`)

Comment: `\citep` is a `natbib` backwards compatibility alias. The `biblatex` name of the command is `\parencite`. But to ease the transition for `natbib` users you can get `natbib` names like `\citep` and `\citet` if you ask for it with `natbib=true,`. I usually prefer not to load the `natbib` compatibility module and stick to the pure `biblatex` names. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864

Comment: Note that there *is* a difference between the starred versions `\citep*` and `\parencite*`.

Comment: @moewe Based in your comment the least effort solution would be change all `\citep` to `\parencite`, so I avoid the mix. I also understand that is better to stick to pure `biblatex`, may I ask you how can I take away `natbib=true`, if I also use `\citet`? I like the format `Knuth (2001)`. How can I substitute it in `biblatex`?

Comment: `\textcite`, see my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are using `biblatex` with the `natbib` compatibility option (`natbib=true,`) to ease transition between `biblatex` and `natbib` (or vice versa),

- `\citep` is a compatibility alias for `\parencite` and
- `\citet` is an alias for `\textcite`.
- Furthermore, `\citealp` and `\citealt` are both aliases for `\cite`.
- Additionally, there is some rudimentary support for `natbib`'s `\defcitealias`.
- Finally, there are `\citeauthor*` and `\citeyearpar`.

So in your example there is no (and there should not be any) difference between `\citep{knuth2001things}` and `\parencite{knuth2001things}`.

There is, however, a difference between the starred versions:

- The `natbib` names `\citep*`/`\citet*` produce citations with a local setting of `maxnames=999`, which means that all authors will be shown.
- The `biblatex` name `\parencite*` produces citations without author names.

The `natbib` compatibility option will do slightly more, though. As explained in [Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864) it will also set

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

---

I usually prefer not to load the `natbib` compatibility mode in `biblatex` and prefer to use the `biblatex` names, but muscle memory and old habits can certainly mean that the `natbib` compatibility mode is useful for you. Even more so if you expect to have to go back to `natbib` commands at some point (not many journals accept `biblatex` submissions).

Just keep in mind that the two quirks of `natbib` compatibility mode mentioned above. The behaviour of the starred version differs from standard `biblatex` and it sets `nameyeardelim`.

Comment: Thanks! You answered **everything** I asked, and more... :)