# Short citeauthor for bib (backend biber)

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to cite the authors of a publication. Say "A. Foo, B. Bar, and C. FooBar".

Using `\citeauthor` from biblatex with Biber backend it produces:

> Foo, Bar and FooBar.

Great!

I am looking for some command (something like `\shortciteauthor` maybe) that produces only the name from the first author with "et al." afterwards.

So instead of above I only want

> Foo et al.

Is there something like this? Sorry for not providing a MWE I didn't come up with something really short enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the starred version `\citeauthor*`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\citeauthor*{aksin}

\citeauthor{aksin}

\citeauthor*{companion}

\citeauthor{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın et al.//Aksın et al.//Goossens et al.//Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin]

Note that if you use the `natbib` compatibility mode (`natbib=true,`, [Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864)), the meaning of `\citeauthor*` is inverted: it prints *all* authors. In that case you can restore the original `\citeauthor*` which only prints the first author by adding

```
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[][1-1]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: This is beyond great! Even fixing the problem I first encountered by using natbib.
Also: Thanks for your edit, I was kind of in a hurry while asking the question. I promise to learn from it.

I am really greatful for this answer. Thank you!