# How to get Chicago-authordate style in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I am completely new to publication, and the editor of the journal I am about to publish in is requesting me to make sure that the bibliography follows the so-called Chicago-authordate style. The editor has also shared this [link](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-2.html) with me. I am trying to make sure that I get the correct style by loading `biblatex` as follows in my preamble

```
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber,natbib,sortcites=true,language=british]{biblatex} % To get a good bibliography
```

The truth, however, is that I do not know whether my loading of `biblatex` is sufficient (i.e., correct) to satisfy the editor's needs. Can anybody tell me if I am missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` is a bit special in the `biblatex` world. While other styles are usually loaded via `\usepackage[style=<style name>]{biblatex}`, `biblatex-chicago` brings its own wrapper package and should be loaded as `\usepackage[<style name>]{biblatex-chicago}`.

For `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style you would use

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that `biblatex` implies a very different workflow than BibTeX/`thebibliography`. Generally speaking you cannot be sure that journals that accept LaTeX submission accept a submission using `biblatex`. Many publishers that work with LaTeX have their own classes or templates that are usually incompatible with `biblatex` and are BibTeX/`thebibliography`-based. Other journals recommend BibTeX or `thebibliography`. I suggest you contact the editor before you start using `biblatex`. Of course this is not an issue if the publisher only ever wants PDFs from you, but as soon as they need the source, you need to make sure that they can work with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful answer. Unfortunately, by applying your suggestions, my LaTex compilation generates 93 errors, most (if not all) of them caused because the commands `\ciep{}` and `\citet{}` break down... Any clue of what's going on here? *EDIT*: I have now added: `\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,natbib,sortcites=true]{biblatex-chicago}` to my preamble and that seems to make it work just fine.

Comment: @Hector If you need to use the old `natbib` names `\citet` and `\citep` (instead of `\textcite` and `\parencite`), you can indeed use the `natbib` option to get the compatibility mode.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, do `\textcite{}` and `\parencite{}` achieve the same as `\citet{}` and `\citep{}`? Are they better than the ones I'm using? If so, why?

Comment: @Hector By default `biblatex` styles usually don't define `\citet` and `\citep`. Instead they define `\textcite` and `\parencite` for those jobs. Because some users are used to the `natbib` names `\citet` and `\citep` or because they want to have an easier way to switch between `natbib` and `biblatex`, `biblatex` has a `natbib` compatibility mode that maps `\citet` or `\textcite` and `\citep` to `\parencite`. It also maps a few other commands (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864), so I usually avoid it and go for `biblatex` names directly.

Comment: Thank you for your (again) very useful comment. I will leave it with the `natbib` compatibility mode for now, and will contact the editors to see if they are happy with `biblatex`. I will then adjust all this according to their answers.